# I have a SfGrid with 5 columns in which 1 column is a multicolumn combobox. I wanted to list items in ComboBox based on the category iam selecting

Tags: datagrid, blazor, syncfusion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuqHj.jpg)

Here in the grid for both the categories all the items are listed under ItemName and ItemCode.

```xml
<SfGrid DataSource="@ItemMasterClass"
                @ref="SfGridRef" GridLines="GridLine.Both" Width="100%" RowHeight="24" AllowFiltering="true"
                AllowPaging="true" Toolbar="@(new List<string>() { "Add", "Delete", "Update", "Cancel" })" Height="@GridHeight">
                <GridFilterSettings Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.FilterType.Excel" ShowFilterBarStatus="true"></GridFilterSettings>
                <GridEditSettings AllowAdding="true" AllowEditing="true" AllowDeleting="true" Mode="EditMode.Batch"></GridEditSettings>
                <GridEvents RowSelected="RowSelectHandler" OnCellSave="CellSaveHandler" OnBatchDelete="BatchDeleteHandler" OnBatchSave="BatchSaveHandler" OnActionComplete="OnActionComplete" OnRecordDoubleClick="RecordDoubleClickHandler" TValue="dtoItemMasterClassWise"></GridEvents>
                <GridPageSettings PageSize="50"></GridPageSettings>
                <GridColumns>
                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.ID) HeaderText="ID" IsPrimaryKey="true" Visible="false" Width="120"></GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.Category) HeaderText="Category" ValidationRules="@(new ValidationRules{ Required=true})" EditType="EditType.DropDownEdit" Width="100"></GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.Class) HeaderText="Class" ValidationRules="@(new ValidationRules{ Required=true})" EditType="EditType.DropDownEdit" Width="100"></GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.ItemCode) HeaderText="Item Code" ValidationRules="@(new ValidationRules{ Required=true})" Width="90">
                    <EditTemplate>
                    @{
                     <SfComboBox ID="ItemCode" AllowCustom="true" @bind-Value="@((context as dtoItemMasterClassWise).ItemCode)" TItem="dtoItemMaster" TValue="string" DataSource="@ItemMasterList" PopupWidth="400px">
                     <ComboBoxFieldSettings Text="@nameof(dtoItemMaster.ItemCode)" Value="@nameof(dtoItemMaster.ItemCode)" />
                    <div class="row">
                    <ComboBoxTemplates TItem="dtoItemMaster">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3" style="width:220px">ItemCode</div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3" style="width:220px">ItemName</div>
                            </div>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate Context="con">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3" style="width:220px">@((con as dtoItemMaster).ItemCode)</div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3" style="width:220px">@((con as dtoItemMaster).ItemName)</div>
                                                    
                                                </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                       
                    </ComboBoxTemplates>
                    </div>
  
                   <ComboBoxEvents TValue="string" TItem="dtoItemMaster" ValueChange="@DropDownOnChange"></ComboBoxEvents>
                   </SfComboBox>

                   }
                   </EditTemplate>
                   </GridColumn>
                    <GridForeignColumn Field=@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.ItemName) ForeignDataSource="@ItemMasterList" HeaderText="ItemName" ForeignKeyValue="ItemName" Width="150"></GridForeignColumn>

                    <GridColumn Field="@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.Qty)" HeaderText="Quantity" Type="ColumnType.Number" ValidationRules="@(new ValidationRules{ Required=true})" Width="80"> 
                    <EditTemplate>
                            <SfNumericTextBox TValue="decimal" Min="@SetMin" Step=@SetIncrement @bind-Value="((context as dtoItemMasterClassWise).Qty)" @onclick="@ApplyRange"></SfNumericTextBox>
                    </EditTemplate>
                    </GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Field="@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.Priority)" HeaderText="Priority" Type="ColumnType.Number" ValidationRules="@(new ValidationRules{ Required=true})" Width="80"> 
                    <EditTemplate>
                            <SfNumericTextBox TValue="int" Min="@SetMin" Step=@SetIncrement @bind-Value="((context as dtoItemMasterClassWise).Priority)" @onclick="@ApplyRange"></SfNumericTextBox>
                    </EditTemplate>
                    </GridColumn>
                </GridColumns>
            </SfGrid>
        }
```

I am expecting to get only those items whose category is same as selected category.

Comment: You can use a custom adaptor to filter your data source. Implementation details can be found [here on Syncfusion's site](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/combobox/data-source). Scroll down to the "Custom adaptor" area.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change only the multicolumn combo box according to the category selection. Kindly refer to the attached code snippet for your reference.

```
 <SfGrid DataSource="@ItemMasterClass"
    @ref="SfGridRef" GridLines="GridLine.Both" Width="100%" RowHeight="24" AllowFiltering="true"
    AllowPaging="true" Toolbar="@(new List<string>() { "Add", "Delete", "Update", "Cancel" })" >
<GridFilterSettings Type="Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids.FilterType.Excel" ShowFilterBarStatus="true"></GridFilterSettings>
<GridEditSettings AllowAdding="true" AllowEditing="true" AllowDeleting="true" Mode="EditMode.Batch"></GridEditSettings>
<GridPageSettings PageSize="50"></GridPageSettings>
<GridColumns>
    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.ID) HeaderText="ID" IsPrimaryKey="true" Visible="false" Width="120"></GridColumn>
    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.Category) HeaderText="Category" ValidationRules="@(new ValidationRules{ Required=true})" EditType="EditType.DropDownEdit" Width="100">
        <EditTemplate>
            <SfDropDownList ID="Category" Placeholder="Category" TItem="string" TValue="string" @bind-Value="@((context as dtoItemMasterClassWise).Category)" DataSource="@Categories">
                <DropDownListEvents TValue="string" TItem="string" ValueChange="ValueChange"></DropDownListEvents>
                <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="Category" Value="Category"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
            </SfDropDownList>
        </EditTemplate>
    </GridColumn>
    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.Class) HeaderText="Class" ValidationRules="@(new ValidationRules{ Required=true})" EditType="EditType.DropDownEdit" Width="100"></GridColumn>
    <GridColumn Field=@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.ItemCode) HeaderText="Item Code" ValidationRules="@(new ValidationRules{ Required=true})" Width="90">
        <EditTemplate>
            @{
                var value = ((context as dtoItemMasterClassWise).Category);

                <SfComboBox ID="ItemCode" AllowCustom="true" @bind-Value="@((context as dtoItemMasterClassWise).ItemCode)" TItem="dtoItemMaster" TValue="string" DataSource="@ItemMasterList" PopupWidth="400px">
                    <ComboBoxFieldSettings Text="@nameof(dtoItemMaster.ItemCode)" Value="@nameof(dtoItemMaster.ItemCode)" />
                    <div class="row">
                        <ComboBoxTemplates TItem="dtoItemMaster">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3" style="width:220px">ItemCode</div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3" style="width:220px">ItemName</div>
                                </div>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate Context="con">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-3" style="width:220px">@((con as dtoItemMaster).ItemCode)</div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3" style="width:220px">@((con as dtoItemMaster).ItemName)</div>

                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                        </ComboBoxTemplates>
                    </div>
               
                </SfComboBox>

            }
        </EditTemplate>
    </GridColumn>
    <GridColumn Field="@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.Qty)" HeaderText="Quantity" Type="ColumnType.Number" ValidationRules="@(new ValidationRules{ Required=true})" Width="80">
        <EditTemplate>
            <SfNumericTextBox TValue="decimal" Min="@SetMin" Step=@SetIncrement @bind-Value="((context as dtoItemMasterClassWise).Qty)"></SfNumericTextBox>
        </EditTemplate>
    </GridColumn>
    <GridColumn Field="@nameof(dtoItemMasterClassWise.Priority)" HeaderText="Priority" Type="ColumnType.Number" ValidationRules="@(new ValidationRules{ Required=true})" Width="80">
        <EditTemplate>
            <SfNumericTextBox TValue="int" Min="@SetMin" Step=@SetIncrement @bind-Value="((context as dtoItemMasterClassWise).Priority)" ></SfNumericTextBox>
        </EditTemplate>
    </GridColumn>
</GridColumns>
```

```
@code{
private SfGrid<dtoItemMasterClassWise> SfGridRef;
public List<string> Categories = new List<string>() { "Books", "Uniforms" };
public List<dtoItemMasterClassWise> ItemMasterClass { get; set; }
public List<dtoItemMaster> ItemMasterList { get; set; }

public int SetMin { get; set; } = 2;
public int SetIncrement { get; set; } = 2;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    ItemMasterClass = GetAllRecords();
}

public List<dtoItemMasterClassWise> GetAllRecords()
{
    List<dtoItemMasterClassWise> data = new List<dtoItemMasterClassWise>();
    int count = 1000;
    int id = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        data.Add(new dtoItemMasterClassWise() { ID = count + 1, Category = "Books", Class = "FS1", Priority = i + 1, Qty = 1, ItemCode = "FSPES18" });
        data.Add(new dtoItemMasterClassWise() { ID = count + 2, Category = "Uniforms", Class = "FS2", Priority = i + 2, Qty = 1, ItemCode = "BLZ4XL" });
        data.Add(new dtoItemMasterClassWise() { ID = count + 3, Category = "Books", Class = "FS3", Priority = i + 3, Qty = 1, ItemCode = "FSPES18" });
        data.Add(new dtoItemMasterClassWise() { ID = count + 4, Category = "Uniforms", Class = "FS4", Priority = i + 4, Qty = 1, ItemCode = "BLZ4XL" });
        data.Add(new dtoItemMasterClassWise() { ID = count + 5, Category = "Books", Class = "FS5", Priority = i + 5, Qty = 1, ItemCode = "FSPES18" });
        count += 5;
        id += 5;
    }
    return data;
}

public class dtoItemMasterClassWise
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
}

public List<dtoItemMaster> ItemMasterList1 { get; set; } = new List<dtoItemMaster>()
{
        new dtoItemMaster() { ItemCode = "FSPES18",ItemName="PE Shorts nursury & FS-18" },
        new dtoItemMaster() { ItemCode = "DSPES17",ItemName="Book-3 & DS-17" },
        new dtoItemMaster() { ItemCode = "FSPES16",ItemName="PE Shorts nursury & FS-16" },
        new dtoItemMaster() { ItemCode = "DSPES18",ItemName="Book-2 & DS-18" },
        new dtoItemMaster() { ItemCode = "FSPES13",ItemName="PE Shorts nursury & FS-13" }

};

public List<dtoItemMaster> UniformList ()
{
    List < dtoItemMaster > data = new List<dtoItemMaster>();
    data.Add(new dtoItemMaster() { ItemCode = "FSPES18", ItemName = "PE Shorts nursury & FS-18" });
    data.Add(new dtoItemMaster() { ItemCode = "FSPES16", ItemName = "PE Shorts nursury & FS-16" });
    data.Add(new dtoItemMaster() { ItemCode = "FSPES13", ItemName = "PE Shorts nursury & FS-13" });

    return data;

}

public List<dtoItemMaster> BookList ()
{
    List < dtoItemMaster > data = new List<dtoItemMaster>();
    data.Add(new dtoItemMaster() { ItemCode = "DSPES17", ItemName = "Book-3 & DS-17" });
    data.Add(new dtoItemMaster() { ItemCode = "DSPES18", ItemName = "Book-2 & DS-18" });
    return data;
}



public class dtoItemMaster
{
    public string ItemCode{ get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}



public void ValueChange(@Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.ChangeEventArgs<string, string> args)
{
    if(args.Value=="Books")
    {
        ItemMasterList = BookList();
    }
    else if(args.Value=="Uniforms")
    {
        ItemMasterList = UniformList();
    }
    else
    {
        ItemMasterList = ItemMasterList1;
    }
    SfGridRef.PreventRender(false);

}
```

}